# How to predict training time (and/or required RAM) for neural network training?

Tags: matlab, resources, neural-network, training-data

This may be too general of a question, but in essence I'm trying to predict how long it will take to train a feed forward neural network for regression given the number of training data, and number/organization of nodes.  I need to do this because I will be using a university cluster to perform the training and when I submit the job I need to do so while specifying expected time, as well as requesting RAM and number of CPU cores.

I am working in Matlab.

Right now my network it has as input a 400-element vector and outputting a 36 element vector (regression fit to training data).

Given 5000 training data points, how can I predict what resources I will need/how long it will take to run on these resources?  (I can have up to 1tb of RAM, and there may be ways to implement gpu's but I haven't figured out how to do so yet.)

Any help or pointers to other resources would be very appreciated.

Comment: You have some options: 1. Always specify the maximum amount of time. You can kill your code anytime if it is not progressing well (I assume your NN library saves the model regularly) 2. Submit a job, check how much time the network spends in doing (say) 5 epochs, and then multiply that accordingly to get the total time 3. For RAM, you may be able to calculate the number of bytes needed per batch for your network, but again you can use the same trick in (2), that's quicker. I don't know if you can calculate time beforehand just by looking at the network.

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that given the amount of interest in neural network now someone would have come up with theoretical models for predicting training time and other parameters.  Thanks, nonetheless.